# Disable dates before today in angular ui datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-services

The website is confusing! How do I disable days prior to this one?

angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (ctrl + f mindate)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the controller

```
var date = new Date();
$scope.minDate = date.setDate((new Date()).getDate());
```

and set min-date="minDate" in your datepicker

```
<datepicker name="date" ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" format-day='d' max-mode="day" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
```